# NetBeans link to line in source

Tags: netbeans

I have quite a complicated code source and I have commented and split it as best I could and created a table of content. I would love to be able to simply click/ctrl + click on one of the lines in my table of content and automatically put my view to the line/link I specified. Is that possible in NetBeans?

Answer (score 1):

You could use bookmarks which are supported by Netbeans. Under "Window / IDE Tools / Bookmarks" you can open the bookmark window which gives you an overview over all bookmarks which can be also renamed. From this window you can navigate via double-click to your bookmarks.

No exactly what you had in mind but a viable alternative.

(see also http://wiki.netbeans.org/EditorBookmarks72)